# Two geometrical objects in same dimensional plane are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What can be a good way to prove that two geometrical objects in same dimensional plane are homeomorphic??

For example....to show that a circle and a ellipse is homeomorphic in $\Bbb R^2$ and a parabola with equation $y = x^2$ and the real line i.e. $\Bbb R$ are homeomorphic.

For the second one one can see that projection function i.e. $f(x,x^2) = x$ of the parabola to the real line serves our process.

And for the first one if I bring the circle and the ellipse to the same center by transformation and define a function that maps a point on the circle to that point of the ellipse which is found by intersecting the line from center through the point on the circle with the ellipse....the function then serves.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "geometrical objects" Do you just mean curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as in your examples?

Answer (score 1):

Exhibit a particular homeomorphism in each case and prove that it's a homeomorphism.  The mapping $x\mapsto (x,x^2)$ is a homeomorphism from the line to the parabola.

If the circle and the ellipse have the same center, draw a ray from that center, and map the point where the ray intersects the circle to the point where the ray intersects the ellipse.  That's a homeomorphism.

Then there's the moderately nitpicking work of proving that those mappings are bijections and that they're continuous in both directions.

In the case of the circle and the ellipse, there may be other homeomorphisms that are easier to do that last part with.  Maybe $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\mapsto(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$?

Comment: For cases that involve compact subsets of the plane (like the circle and ellipse), one can avoid proving directly that the inverse of the given bijection is continuous by using the fact that a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff one is a homeomorphism.

Comment: . . . but of course one would still have to prove _that_. ${}\qquad{}$